# send emails with templates in c# windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am new in windows services.

I am facing some problems :-

1. I have to reboot system every time to reinstall it.
2. Can I debug my code in windows services?
3. Is there any way to install it using command prompt (I have used
   Developer Command Prompt for VS2015).

I have created a service to send simple emails and now I have changed the code to send emails with templates but its not working.

**Error** :- "Service Error on: 10/04/2017 07:40:00 PM Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\~\Payment-Receipt.htm'".

File.ReadAllText is not replacement of Server.MapPath so what should be used?

```
private void SchedularCallback(object e)
{
    try
    {               
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();                
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getAllInvoices"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                       
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }                
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string name = row["FirstName"].ToString();
            string email = row["EmailId"].ToString(); 
            long InvoiceId = Convert.ToInt64(row["InvoiceId"].ToString());
            string amount = row["SettledAmount"].ToString();  
            WriteToFile("Trying to send email to: " + name + " " + email);                 
            string body = this.createEmailBody(name, "Please check your account Information", amount);
            using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], email))
            {
                mm.Subject = "Package Changed";                        
                mm.Body = body;
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
                smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
                System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                credentials.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
                credentials.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = credentials;
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
                smtp.Send(mm);                                      
            }
        }

        this.ScheduleService();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
      using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("SimpleService"))
        {
            serviceController.Stop();
        }
    }
}

private string createEmailBody(string userName, string title, string amount)
{
    string body = string.Empty;        
    string originalTemplate = File.ReadAllText(@"~\Payment-Receipt.htm");
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(originalTemplate))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }        
    body = body.Replace("{FirstName}", userName); //replacing the required things             
    body = body.Replace("{Amount}", amount);
    return body;
}

private void WriteToFile(string text)
{
    string path = "C:\\ServiceLog.txt";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")));
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it is possible to debug a service using Visual Studio 2015. You would need to install the remote debugging tool on the endpoint. As long as you're not running this on a production system, that should be fine. If the process is local, then you should be able to just attach to process. The error you are receiving is because you rae trying to read a relative path, though. I would stick the path in my config file, and just read that. If you print to a debug file the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property, you'll see that your service is running in a Windows system directory.

Comment: thank you so much @PSGuy.., can you tell me any way to reinstall it without rebooting systme..

Comment: I apologize,  I'm not sure about that last part. I would recommend reading the Microsoft docs on services. That's going to be your best bet.

Comment: I am not able to upvote you..

Comment: sunny701, I added my comment as an answer. I did add some additional content to help clarify it as well, so that it could be more useful to others in the index of answered questions in the future. Did you manage to get the last part sorted? If not, I can go find the Microsoft docs pertaining to that particular part.

Comment: yes we can use developer command prompt and commands then no need to restart..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible to debug a service using Visual Studio 2015. You would need to install the remote debugging tool on the endpoint if you're running on a remote server. To my knowledge, you would need to run the service as its own process (it can't be hosted inside of svchost), but I normally run services separately inside their own process before trying to deploy to the production system. As long as you're not running this service on a production system, running the remote debugging tools should be fine. If the process is local, then you should be able to just attach to the process.

The error you are receiving is because you are trying to read a relative path, though. I would stick the path in my config file, and just read that. If you print to a debug file the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` property, you'll see that your service is running in a Windows system directory.